# can't remove Postman from Ubuntu 16.04 machine

Tags: software-uninstall

Somehow I have ended up with one version of Postman installed on /usr/opt as a folder and on /usr/bin and /usr/lib.

I tried to clean the mess and remove postman (all of it) especially the one stacked in usr/bin, which is (from what I have read) not a proper place for it. I failed using all conventional methods: apt remove --purge (=>*unable to locate*), synaptic Ubuntu Software Center.

But Postman is there and it works. What is going on?

Comment: How did you install it?  /usr/opt/ is NOT part of the a normal Linux installation.

Comment: Try installing it with `apt` and then removing it.

Comment: "How did you install it? /usr/opt/ is NOT part of the a normal Linux installation. "          About that. I do not know. I downloaded a zip and it installed itself there, did not asked. By the way, when I looked into my folders most of the external apps have installed to /usr/bin + /usr/lib. This keeps me wander why is that since from what people suggest non essential stuff should be kept in /usr/local/bin + /usr/local/lib. So, which folder is a good place to store apps and how to control the destination? Somehow on >opt<  ended Chrome, Sublime and one Postman.